# I can't copy equations written in MathType to Microsoft Word anymore

Tags: microsoft-word, mathtype

I've been using [MathType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathType) for almost five years, but I've never faced this problem until today. Currently, I'm using MathType `v7.4.8.0` and Microsoft Word 2016. I had written equations in MathType like this:

[image: Image. A screenshot of a window for a Windows program called Math Type. It shows three example equations in mathematical notation]

Then I select all the equations by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and Copy them using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Then I paste them in Microsoft Word 2016 using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. But it shows me this:

[image: Image. A screenshot of a Microsoft Word document. It is almost entirely blank, except for the phrase, right curly brace, space, Embed Equation, dot, D, S, M, T, 4, space, left curly brace]

I had never faced such an issue before. How can I fix it?

---

**Appendix**
As you know, there is another way to paste clipboard to Microsoft Word, by <kbd>Right Click</kbd> then <kbd>Paste Options</kbd>. When I move the pointer on <kbd>P</kbd> button (showed below) without clicking on it, it shows the preview in the right way:

[image: Image. A screenshot of a blank Microsoft Word document. There is a Paste Options preview overlay showing the example Math Type equations created earlier]

But after clicking, it shows `{ EMBED Equation.DSMT4 }`! Strange .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Issue [solved](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/microsoft-equation-how-to-get-rid-of-embed/453123e5-affd-466d-8f20-0137727c76c1#:%7E:text=Press%20Alt%2BF9%20to%20toggle%20the%20view%20from%20field%20codes%20(what%20you%27re%20seeing)%20to%20field%20results.) using this <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> hotkey. Now it pastes equations normally:

[image: Image. A screenshot of a Microsoft Word document showing three example equations in mathematical notation]

Comment: For anyone curious, Alt + F9 toggles the view from field codes (e.g. `{ EMBED Equation.DSMT4 }`) to field results, according to the linked Microsoft answer.

Comment: And to clarify, the paste actually worked correctly, it was just the way the equations were displayed (or rather, weren't) which was affected.

Answer (score 22):

#### Equations are displayed as `{ EMBED.Equation }` in Microsoft Word

There are several different ways to fix this.

> These representations are a feature in Microsoft Word called Field Codes. They are used to help Word identify objects, such as equations, in your document. You only see them when the option is turned on, in which case they appear on-screen, in print, or both on the screen and in print.

1. Change your view settings in Word

> - Launch Word.
> - Select
>
>   - Office Button > Word Options > Advanced (Word 2007)
>   - File tab > Options > Advanced (Word 2010 and later)
>   - Word > Preferences > View (Word for Mac)
> - Uncheck the box for "Field Codes" or "Field codes instead of values".
> - Press OK (Windows) or close Preferences (Mac).
>
> Other ways you can toggle this property are:

2. Keyboard shortcut

> The Word keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Alt+F9</kbd> (Win) or <kbd>⌥+F9</kbd> (Mac).

3. Word toolbar

> The toolbar button in Word looks like `{a}`.

Source: [Equations are displayed as { EMBED.Equation } in Microsoft Word - MathType - Documentation - WIRIS](https://docs.wiris.com/en/mathtype/office_tools/support_notices/tn73#applicability)